# add dll to IIS server

Tags: c#, iis-8.5

I created a rest services in asp.net and running fine on visual studio but  not after hosting on IIS server .

I searched and find that IIS server does't allow DLL, its blocked, so we need to unblocked and add DLL.

My question is how to unblock and add DLL on IIS server please help me.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Unclear, too broad, etc. - based on what you've posted regarding "_IIS doesn't allow dll"_ sounds like a server setup gone horribly wrong/lacking - and that topic is for your hosting provider and yourself to iron out.

Comment: my project using many dll when hosting on IIS server then these all dll are not getting by IIS server

Answer (score 2):

Use this msdn [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/globalmodules/add) to add global modules, follow the steps and you should encounter no serious problem.

Use this to enable/add [Native Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771133(v=ws.10).aspx). the guide is related to iis 7 but I do believe you will be able to persist it on later versions of iis as well.